# vb.net Combo-box DataSource VS DataBindings.Add

Tags: vb.net, combobox

In vb.net, when trying to fill a `combobox` from dataset
what is the difference between these two methods

```
 combobox.DataBindings.Add("datasource", dataset, "tblName")

 combobox.DataSource = dataset.Tables("tblName")
```

both methods will fill the combo but sometimes DataBindings don't !
so is there any special case that i have to use one ?

Answer (score 0):

**combobox.DataBindings.Add** - Adds the specified Binding to the (Existing)collection.

**combobox.DataSource** - Gets or sets the data source(new) for this ComboBox.